# Facebook API graph - max 25 public events of a page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, events

I'm trying to get all public events of a users page. Now I realized that Facebook API graph only returns a maximum of 25 events of one page.

Is there a way to get all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

There will be a "next" link in the API result, which is the API call for the next 25 items. You can also use the limit parameter to get more items per call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and help!! I'll try it with the limit parameter.
Best regards